# How to create thread_local variable in llvm ir?

Tags: clang, llvm, llvm-ir

Is there a way to create a new threa_local variable in llvm ir via pass?

Comment: Thread support is something your compiler's runtime library has to provide (if the language supports multithreading at all, some languages don't), so creating a thread-local variable is a matter of calling the right function in your runtime library.

Answer (score 3):

Sure! `GlobalVariable` ctor has the necessary TLS bits to set: https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1GlobalVariable.html#af9ea64c7dae47dcfa2c9f5775fb5915d

Note that thread local variables require some support from the runtime, etc. So, it's not something that could be usable everywhere (and some platforms do not support them at all).